# 100x loop, get rownames from dataframe A and add as a column to a new dataframe B each time, ending with 100 columns in B

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, r-rownames

I want to execute a 100x [loop](/questions/tagged/loop), get rownames from a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) `A` and add its `rownames` as values in a column to a new [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) `B` each time, ending with 100 columns in `B`. I am beating my head against the wall here trying to do this, as I seem to overwrite B every way I have tried it.

```
     data <- bs.exp.sorted.1198.input
     outsft = dataframe
     outsamps = dataframe 
     samples<- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 60, ncol = 1))
     currentsamps =dataframe 
     itnumb=100 

    for(i in 1:itnumb){
    subsamp <- data[sample(nrow(data), 60), ]

    powers =c(c(1:10), seq(from=12,to=20,by=2))
    sft =pickSoftThreshold(bs.exp.sorted.1198.input, powerVector = powers, verbose=5)


    outsft <- rbind(outsft, sft$fitIndices[,2])

    currentsamps <- as.data.frame(rownames(subsamp))
    output <- add_column(samples, currentsamps)

    }
```

output always contains a column of 0s (which I had to include to get it to work... And whatever the last set of rownames were in the loop. I want to save ALL the rownames in one big dataframe. This should be a simple task, but it has me stumped, and at this point, infuriated. Any suggestions?
 Thanks.

Comment: Is the data.frame A the only input object you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
initial_rows = 100
initial_df = data.frame( col1 = rnorm( initial_rows ),  
                         row.names = 1:initial_rows )
stores_names = rownames( initial_df )

chunk_size = 10
n_repetitions = 10
result = data.frame( matrix( NA_character_, 
                             nrow = chunk_size, ncol = n_repetitions ) )

for ( i_rep in seq_len(n_repetitions) ) {

  current_names = sample( stores_names, chunk_size ) 
  result[ , i_rep ] = current_names

}

> result
   X1  X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  72  62 24 35 80 48  6 79 17  96
2  66   4 59 39 32 67 95 96 89  26
3  34  21 96 75 22 87  8 49 98  50
4  40  33 74 90 39  2 86 78 15   3
5  87  12 70 72 62 98 69  4  1  32
6  98  43  7 38 18 57 83 47 35  41
7  28  70  6 84 30  4 54 46  4  35
8  94 100 80 36 84  7 56 36 73   9
9  60  88 28 11 73 32  3 23 85  67
10 69  69 68 69  4 17 60 63 62  47
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks! What a relief.

Comment: @Zoidberg_OuuuO I am glad it worked out. One advice, don't use offensive language even if I sympathize with the frustration.